# Failed to start apparmor initialization

Tags: boot, 17.10, apparmor

I am facing this problem which is shown on the below screenshot.

[image: Ubuntu Bionic Beaver 17]

Comment: What did you find when you looked at the details as to the 'failure' ?  I'd expect that information would contain more helpful clues for you, and us to aid you.

Comment: I don't know how to open the systemctl. This error appears when I am trying to boot...

Comment: No problem; it's a command you type in exactly as the message says. `systemctl status apparmor.service`  (or everything inside the 'quotes') to view details as to why 'failure' was printed.  To open a terminal (where the command gets entered) you can go thru your menu, or hit <ctrl>+<alt>+<T>   or or just use a term (ctrl+alt+f4 or another fn key)

Comment: I can not open the OS, on boot this error happend and stuck before start the OS.

Comment: Can't you switch to a [pseudo] terminal and login?  ie. ctrl+alt+f4 (or another term) and login?  If your system doesn't get that far, you'll have to "e" (edit) your grub entry, I'd remove 'quiet splash" (mostly out of habit) and importantly add a '1' (or 'single' to disable gui etc).  If you are being correct, and using OS correctly I'm sorry - many people on here mean the 'gui' when they say OS (the gui is just a user-space program running on the OS)

Comment: I don't know if I understand what you are saying. But what happend is that I powered up the computer, Ubuntu starts to running and in a few seconds the attached screen appears with the fail on apparmor and that is it, no command work, no mouse, nothing happend...
My question is how can I leave this screen and open the ubuntu again?

Comment: I asked firstly if you can switch from your gui to a [pseudo] terminal, ie. trying ctrl+alt+f4 to switch to term4. If this worked you'd get a text login prompt  (where you can login, do things)....  My second suggestion was to reboot & when you get to grub, instead of pressing <enter> to start Ubuntu, hitting <e> to edit then making changes to the 'linux' line with purpose of temporarily disabling gui so you have a workable system (at terminal).

Comment: Works, I have now access to the terminal, but seems to have no internet connection, I tried to update the system and it was failed...
Any suggestions?

Comment: If you entered the '1' you'll be in runlevel 1 (if you enter `runlevel` it'll tell you your runlevel; default is 5; 1 or single-user mode is without networking by default) so its expected.  This is a diagnosis mode where you have full access to your filesystem, can make changes & explore problems & fix. You need runlevel=2+ for networking. Now you could try using the aforementioned [`systemctl..`] command to see if you get extra messages (I don't know what runlevel apparmor starts at; it may not yet be started)

Comment: The final solution was completely remove and reinstall ubuntu. =(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The final solution was completely remove and reinstall ubuntu. =(